# Limiting cryptomeria height

Tags: pruning

Recently bought a new house, and we have a cryptomeria planted about 10' away from it. It's currently about 20' tall and healthy.

I know cryptomerias can grow very tall and we do not want to allow for that. The tree is too close to the house and we don't want the risk of it ever falling onto the residence. The current height is perfect.

What is the best way to prune it for height control?

Answer (score 1):

These trees can reach 60 feet and they are fast growing; if you're concerned  its too close to the house (and it sounds like it is) you might consider removing it. Trying to keep the height controlled and at 20' is probably not an option. You could, though, cut the trunk down to about 3 feet and let it regrow, then repeat when it gets to the height you want, see here https://www.hunker.com/13428950/how-to-prune-cryptomeria